# Key authentication module Geoserver - authkey

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I have a problem with this GeoServer [plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/authkey/index.html). I have done the following:

- downloaded the plugin from
  http://gridlock.opengeo.org/geoserver/2.2.x/community-latest/
- extracted archive to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/
- restarted tomcat6 uncommented required line from /geoserver_data/security/authkeys.properties restarted tomcat6 again
- and still I can access all WMS services without authkey in the URL

What am I doing wrong?

I am probably forgetting something and can’t figure what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have not enabled security on GeoServer. You need to secure your instance of GeoServer with one or more user accounts and then you associate a range of authkeys with those users.

You will also need to set the WMS to "Hide" mode so that it does not broadcast its capabilities unless being accessed by a user or someone making a request using the authkey(s) you have setup.